# Change NSTextView content outside an IBAction Method

Tags: objective-c, methods, nstextview

I'm trying to modify the string contents of an NSTextView object. So far I've been able to make it work with the following code.

.h file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface InterfaceManager : AppDelegate {
    IBOutlet NSTextView *content;
}

-(IBAction)displayOutput:(id)sender;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "InterfaceManager.h"

@implementation InterfaceManager

-(IBAction)displayOutput:(id)sender {
    [content setString:@"This is a string"];
}

@end
```

which all works perfectly fine and does exactly what I want.

---

However I need to be able to do the same thing in a void method. Here's what I've tried.

.h file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface InterfaceManager : AppDelegate {
    IBOutlet NSTextView *content;
}

-(void)displayOutput:(NSString *)string;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "InterfaceManager.h"

@implementation InterfaceManager

-(void)displayOutput:(NSString *)string {
    [content setString:string];
}

@end
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong and how to I fix it to make it work?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you set the text when a button is pushed, but you also want to set the text without the user pushing a button. If that it the case then you don’t need a "void method", you can use any method to do it. For example, I set the client name in my options screen when I first enter the screen using this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // All games allow a client and rewards
    if (self.currentClient) {
        self.clientInput.text = self.currentClient;
    }
}
```

If you want to have a separate method to set the string, I think you can use something like this:

```
-(void)myContentSettingMethod {
     [self.content setString:@"This is a string"];
}
```

and then call it whenever you want to set the content.